# Show all the columns in a single row and not overflow to next row in HTML

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I have an HTML page with lay out something like this:

[image]

The problem is. I want the MSAN and Users column in the same row, otherwise, for a large number of records, it won't be suitable. this is my HTML File. Ignore how the values are being shown or which.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <br>
      <h1 style="text-align: center">License Generator</h1><br>
      <div class="row" [hidden]="!deleteMessage">
           
                <!--<div class="col-sm-4"></div> -->
                <div> <!---->
                        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                                <strong>License Deleted</strong>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="col-sm-4"></div> -->
        </div>           
    </div>

  
  <div class="panel-body">
      <table  class="table table-hover table-sm" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions"
      [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"  >
          <thead class="thead-light">
              <tr>
                  <th>Customer ID</th>
                  <th>Hardware Key</th>
                  <th>Product</th>
                  <th>License Key</th>
                  <th>Action</th>  
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
               <tr *ngFor="let student of students ">
                  <td>33333</td>
                  <td>22222</td>
                  <td>ABC</td>
                  <td><textarea rows="2" cols="20" wrap="hard">fxLBJ0BF5b+CLBCW9xamqsCgP0AyVIVpCCiYGI3WfEOAPPB7nVgHipERQmv2wVJYQI9PwfpS+4qP5owl4eDfI/f42cbu+SBTty3Sk/sGzZfon1xUndfAzsqbHD/DbFjQAtbpzeB7yr7AtNSV22WBv/lwC4ZW0k1KGR44tNM8aW5UQf9/WmuKeM/dFKIiW6vKMd9dn35jJ5AdlUIBRKwTFg==</textarea></td>
                  <td><button (click)="deleteStudent(student.student_id)" class='btn btn-primary'><i class="fa fa-futboll-0">Delete</i></button>&nbsp;
                    <button (click)="updateStudent(student.student_id)" class='btn btn-primary'
                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Update</button>&nbsp;
                    <button (click)="updateStudent(student.student_id)" class='btn btn-primary'
                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Copy License Key</button>
                  </td>
                </tr> 
          </tbody><br>
          <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Max MSAN</th>
                <th>Max Users</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let student of students ">
             <td>10000</td>
             <td>10000</td>
           </tr> 
        </tbody><br>
      </table>
  </div>
</div> 

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
                <form [formGroup]="studentupdateform" #updstu (ngSubmit)="updateStu(updstu)">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center">Update Student</h4>
              
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body" *ngFor="let student of studentlist " >
                <div [hidden]="isupdated">

                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  formControlName="student_id" [(ngModel)]="student.student_id">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Student Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  formControlName="student_name" [(ngModel)]="student.student_name"  >
                            </div>
                    
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Student Email</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="student_email" [(ngModel)]="student.student_email">
                            </div>
                    
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Student Branch</label>
                                  <select class="form-control" formControlName="student_branch" required>                                   
                                    <option value="B-Tech" [selected]="'B-Tech' == student.student_branch">ZMS</option>
                                  </select>                               
                            </div>                   
                  </div>  
                  <div [hidden]="!isupdated">
                      <h4>Student Detail Updated!</h4>
                  </div>        
                    
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer" >
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [hidden]="isupdated">Update</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="changeisUpdate()">Close</button>
            </div>
            
        </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

There is nothing in the CSS file. If I try to keep all columns in same , then I lose the Search field and the number of entries data. I have taken help of a Spring Boot project from a website and got this, but not able to get this done. Please help. Stuck on this for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add  `white-space:nowrap;` to all the `td` and I think it should solve the problem
this is what nowrap does:

> Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text
> will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line
> until a 
>  tag is encountered.took from w3school

Comment: Do I add this to the CSV file and then add asa class or it works directly?

Comment: in css you can add stuff by two way inline style effect directly and it has the highest priority (more the id and class) or the better way as I think from the css class.

you can add it directly to the line but it's better to give a class and then edit in CSS file  so if you need to use is in other places you can